# How to set Updates to this data - Laravel/Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have a web application where the user shall be able to change MariaDB records via a GUI inside the browser.
In this GUI, the user sees a list of the records visible for him. Whatever he can see, he has permission to delete or change as well.

To change a DB record, he simply has to click the fields he wants to change inside the list and then press the "send" button.
In his HTTP request, the id associated with the record will be transmitted so the backend can identify the respective record inside the DB and apply the changes.

Now, Im rather new to Laravel/Lumen. To fetch the list the user can apply changes to in the first place, I have the following code:

```
$join = coretable::with($permittedTables)->get();
```

The `$permittedTables` is an array of tablenames, so any number or combination of tables might be joined to coretable. 
For example, a fetch can look like this:

```
[{
  "Internal_key": "TESTKEY_1",
  "extensiontable_itc": {
    "description": "EXTENSION_iTC_1"
  },
  "extensiontable_sysops": {
    "description": "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_1"
  }
}, {
  "Internal_key": "TESTKEY_2",
  "extensiontable_itc": {
    "description": "EXTENSION_ITC_2"
  },
  "extensiontable_sysops": {
    "description": "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_2"
  }
}, {
  "Internal_key": "TESTKEY_3",
  "extensiontable_itc": {
    "description": "EXTENSION_ITC_3"
  },
  "extensiontable_sysops": {
    "description": "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_3"
  }
}, {
  "Internal_key": "TESTKEY_4",
  "extensiontable_itc": {
    "description": "EXTENSION_ITC_4"
  },
  "extensiontable_sysops": {
    "description": "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_4"
  }
}, {
  "Internal_key": "TESTKEY_5",
  "extensiontable_itc": {
    "description": "EXTENSION_ITC_5"
  },
  "extensiontable_sysops": {
    "description": "EXTENSION_SYSOPS_5"
  }
}]
```

Now, I wondered if I could just reuse the code I've created to fetch the data for setting the data. 
So I used the above shown `$join` and tried to determine the datarecords I want to change.
The attempt looks like this:

```
$join = $join->find("TESTKEY_1");
```

The find however doesnt return anything. 
Considering the structure of the results I'm querying here, is this approach even feasible? Or should I build some new code, fetching the results in a different structure, better suited to have changes applied to it?

Still, is there a way to search these fetchresults for a subset of data and then apply changes to this subset (and persist those changes to the DB, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$join = $join->find("TESTKEY_1");

find method works only for ids.
e.g. $join = $join->find(1);  //1 is id (primary_key) in here.

if you want to find the record by TESTKEY_1
$join = $join->where("Internal_key","TESTKEY_1")->get();
// will return array of all records having **Internal_key** **TESTKEY_1**
if you want only the first record to be fetched 
$join = $join->where("Internal_key","TESTKEY_1")->first();
// will return only first having **Internal_key** **TESTKEY_1** as an array.